# What version of the wreath product embedding theorem is actually stated in the famous paper of Kaloujnine and Krasner?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

This question is inspired by Terry Tao's [blog post](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/10/06/a-trivial-generalisation-of-cayleys-theorem/) and the comments there.  I have always cited M. Krasner and L. Kaloujnine, "Produit complet des groupes de permutations et le problème d'extension de groupes III", Acta Sci. Math. Szeged 14, pp. 69-82 (1951) as the source of the result that if $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup, then the regular action of $G$ on itself is inside of the action of the wreath product $H\wr (G/\mathrm{Core}(H))$ on $H\times G/H$ via the identification of $G$ with $H\times G/H$  using a transversal $T$ for $G/H$ and that replacing $T$ by a different transversal changes the embedding of $G$ by an inner automorphism of the wreath product.

I am aware that this result is implicit in Frobenius's theory of induced representations and the theory of monomial representations of groups (e.g. Chapter 4 this paper of [Ore](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1942-051-00/S0002-9947-1942-0005739-6/S0002-9947-1942-0005739-6.pdf) although $H$ is assumed finite index there) but these authors did not use the wreath product language to the best of my knowledge.

Many people refer only to the special case where $N$ is normal as the Krasner-Kaloujnine embedding. I am now wondering which version they actually stated. The original paper does not seem easy to access by the obvious Google search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original paper (part II of a three part series) is available [here](http://acta.fyx.hu/acta/showCustomerArticle.action?id=6063&dataObjectType=article&returnAction=showCustomerVolume&sessionDataSetId=30c6b17da837ee4c&style=). Page 47 lists the theorem and  discusses in a footnote the relation with Ore's earlier work.

From what I understand, any series of subgroups is allowed in the embedding, they need not be normal.

A more limited version of their theorem is published in part III, available [here](http://acta.fyx.hu/acta/showCustomerArticle.action?id=6072&dataObjectType=article&returnAction=showCustomerVolume&sessionDataSetId=4919364f62e409ab&style=), and this has caused some [confusion](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjournals.cambridge.org%2Farticle_S144678870001483X&ei=XQxFVJq0C8PqOKKLgfgI&usg=AFQjCNHQqwkXO_zu6u385i-N1f_i0GJ4Tg&sig2=PpWVQCSqmEyOC0nSHZ9WPg).

Comment: Thanks for locating it. I will have to read this on a bigger screen then my phone.

Comment: I read the paper about 20 years ago for my thesis. The way I remember their result (and what I definitively used) is that the subgroups don't need to be normal. I'm still puzzled why the result (which is induction for permutation representations) is not put in (more) textbooks.